How to always ignore specific properties during JSON serialization
I do have a class owning 2 DateTime properties for a start- and an enddate. The values are nullable.
   public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
   public DateTime? End { get; set; }

To work a bit easier with these values, I created 2 helper properties.
[JsonIgnore] 
public DateTime StartForComparison => Start ?? DateTime.MinValue;
[JsonIgnore] 
public DateTime EndForComparison => End ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

As you can see, during serialization, these properties should always be ignored. But by default, the JSON settings of the Microsoft implementation states out, that the properties are never ignored.
So I've set the corresponding option while starting my web service.
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
});

But during start, I do get an exception, that setting the attribute 'Always' is not allowed.
The other attributes regarding null or default values don't make any sense, because these properties are never null nor do they have default values.
Does anyone have an idea how I can set this attribute afterwards or is there an alternative solution to exclude these two properties from being serialized?

I don't think you need to change the setting from default. I'll try to compile an example ...

=> https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZiQgZm => Seems to me as if it works as desired with plain default settings?

"But during start, I do get an exception, das setting the attrniute 'Always' is not allowed." - please add full exception text. JsonIgnore should be enough for making the properties ignored on serialization.

"Does anyone have an idea how I can set this attribute afterwards" - what attribute? JsonIgnore?

OK, so: For one - I think it works without changing the setting away from its default. Second: You totally can provide a specialized SerializationOptions object to every Serialize call. Then, there are also custom converters, source generated serializers, ... but again: IMHO none of that is needed.

BTW: Why do you set WriteIndented? That's rather unusual for a Service. You can always have a tool pretty print the json if you need a human to take a look at it for debugging for example.

The exception text is
System.ArgumentException: "The value cannot be 'JsonIgnoreCondition.Always'."

The [JsonIgnore] definitely not works, I post a request via Postman to my endpoint and the response includes these 2 properties. That's why I asked this question here... ;)
See this link, public properties are exported by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties

Wait, slowly. Do you want to exclude Start and End respectively if they are null? And on top of that the ...ForComparison ones always?

Just found the reason for the issue. Currently the framework seems to use Newtonsoft JSON for the serialization of the response of the controller. That's why the Microsoft attribute didn't work.
Now I need to find a way to remove Newtonsoft as a standard serializer.
In several postings I read, that the Microsoft JSON implementation from .NET8 on is much faster then Newtonsoft.

No, I want to exclude the properties StartForComparison and EndForComparison. The properties Start and End are expected to be serialized.

OK, I removed builder.Services.AddNewtonsoftJson() and now the Microsoft property attributes work.

Ah, should have seen that one comming. I stepped into the exact same mine last year.
